# Formik FieldArray doesn't update as expected in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I'm trying to recreate the [FieldArray example](https://formik.org/docs/examples/field-arrays) in Formik but using React Native.

My attempt ([snack here](https://snack.expo.dev/-9POSIu13)) almost works except it looks as though the last TextInputs are being removed rather than the selected ones.

The Text component and the Alert on submission show that the correct items are being deleted but the input fields don't reflect this.

Is there something that I've missed?  I've searched around and the `enableReinitialize` prop is the most common suggestion but that seems to be for when the initial values change, not the current values.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I know it's been a while but did you find a solution to your problem? I'm facing the same; thank you!

Comment: I didn't find a solution, unfortunately.  I decided to change it so you could only delete the last entry (since it looks like that anyway).  Not ideal, but a compromise I could live with.